# Converting traditional line breaks to Markdown double-space newlines

Tags: macos, unix, sed, awk, markdown

I've just learned how to do real line breaks in Markdown, with two spaces at the end of the line. I have a lot of files that I want to convert to this way of doing things because getting used to it is going to make my life a lot easier when using Markdown tools such as Pandoc.

These files currently look like this:

```
Roses are red
Violets are blue

Bananas are yellow

Oranges are orange
```

I'd like to transform paragraphs with more than one line so that the result would look like this:

```
Roses are red<space><space>
Violets are blue

Bananas are yellow

Oranges are orange
```

Sadly my linux fu is not up to the task. I have `\n` end of lines. Here's how I would start it:

```
for i in \*; do sed -e 's/\n/  /g' "$i"; done
```

I have absolutely no idea on how to differentiate line breaks followed by empty lines which shouldn't be modified (line 2), from line breaks followed by text which should be modified by sed (line 1). Also, empty lines (line 3) should be ignored. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this reliably, you need a markdown parser.  (I believe the awk-based solutions will insert spaces at the end of lines in code blocks, too, which you don't want.)  Using pandoc 1.11.1 or later, you can do this:

```
pandoc -fmarkdown_strict+hard_line_breaks -t markdown_strict
```

Note that if you plan to use pandoc as your markdown processor, you can simply leave your files as they are, and use either `markdown+hard_line_breaks` or `markdown_strict+hard_line_breaks` as your input format.

Comment: By far the best solution. Thank you for writing such a great tool!

Answer (score 0):

#### change empty lines

do you mean this? I used `xx` to make it easier to see in output:

```
kent$  awk '{$0=$0"xx"}7' f
Roses are redxx
Violets are bluexx
xx
Bananas are yellowxx
xx
Oranges are orangexx
```

so, each "new line" will be replaced with `two 'x' with newline`. if this is what you are looking for, you could do:

```
awk '{$0=$0"  "}7' file
```

#### without changing empty lines

if you want to ignore empty lines (for empty line don't do any substitution):
check this out:

```
kent$  awk '$0{$0=$0"xx"}7' f
Roses are redxx
Violets are bluexx

Bananas are yellowxx

Oranges are orangexx
```

so you see above the `double x` didn't show on empty lines. you could use the command:

```
awk '$0{$0=$0"  "}7' file
```

### EDIT

```
kent$  awk 'NR==1{p=$0;next}{p=p&&$0?p"xx":p; print p;p=$0}END{print $0}' f
Roses are redxx
Violets are blue

Bananas are yellow

Oranges are orange
```

check the above one-liner, all empty lines and previous line of empty lines are ignored. the last line of the file is ignored too.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I would like to ignore empty lines but also lines like "Violets are bluexx". "Violets are bluexx" doesn't need two spaces at its end because in Markdown its formatting is already handled by the empty line that follows it. In other words I would like to transform "Roses are red" only. Is that easy to do with `awk`?

Comment: @mm2703 check the EDIT, to see if it is what you need

Comment: It certainly looks like it! Sorry I didn't see your edit but I was busy trying Ed's solution.

Comment: Just worth mentioning that on some versions of awk it would print nothing if the input file only contained one line because not all awk versions have access in the END section to the $0, NF, etc. of the last line read. Just something to bear in mind.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you! good to know it.. can you tell which awk doesn't support this, so that I could keep in mind in later coding. thx.

Comment: @Kent - sorry, no, I don't know. It would have to be a non-POSIX awk though. Maybe mawk? Actually, given POSIX requires it, maybe it's not even worth mentioning any more that it's a possibility. I wonder if it might even just be old, broken awk.... Now I have to go investigate - darn!

Comment: Ah, now I remember - POSIX requires that $NF be preserved in the END section but not $0 so it's implementation-dependent what each awk does with that so it is worth bearing mind after all. I still couldn't tell you which awk(s) don't preserve $0 but I have seen people post questions at comp.lang.awk asking why `END{print}` doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
{
    if (NF) {
        head = tail
        tail = "<space><space>"
    }
    else {
        head = ""
        tail = ""
    }
    printf "%s%s%s", head, (NR>1?ORS:""), $0
}
END { print "" }
' file
Roses are red<space><space>
Violets are blue

Bananas are yellow

Oranges are orange
```

Just change `tail = "<space><space>"` to `tail = "  "`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '$!N;/^\s*\n\|\n\s*$/!s/\n/<space><space>&/;P;D file
```

This keeps 2 lines in the pattern space. If the first or second lines are empty i.e the start or end of a paragraph, prints out the first line unchanged. If however they are not, then it prefixes the newline by the desired string.